# Bootstrap Modal not working when clicking button

Tags: html, flask, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a bootstrap modal to pop up when clicking a button. I watched some trailers and did the same. Nothing happens when I click the button. I also copied an modal example from bootstrap but also not working. What is wrong?

here is the code:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should work since it is copied from bootstrap webpage but it is not working.. Please help. I am using Flask if that is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Seems like I had bootstrap v.5 and I did copy modal from bootstrap v.4. It is working now!